# Check if string is starting with prefix

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, if-statement, prefix

I would like to check with javascript if array items starts with the word "prefix".

So far I've done something like this:

```js
let array = ["prefix-word1", "prefix-word2"];

array.forEach(function(element) {
      if (element.lastIndexOf('prefix', 0) == 0) {
        console.log('prefix');
      }
    }
```

For some reason I keep get an error that prefix is not defined. Please help.

Comment: Use `indexOf`, not `lastIndexOf`.

Comment: You have a syntax error, you're missing `)` at the end.

Comment: I don't see any reason for that error. You would get it if you forgot to put quotes around `prefix`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a simple typographical error. The only problem appears to be a missing closing parenthesis on the `forEach`.

Comment: @ggorlen That's probably a copying error, it wouldn't cause the error he says he's getting.

Comment: Sure, but there isn't any error otherwise in the code, so it seems like the problem has been solved or is non-reproducible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one works (check the comments on the code):

```js
let array = ["prefix-word1", "prefix-word2" , "does not start with prefix"];

array.forEach(function(element) {
   // Check if the first word is prefix
   if (element.indexOf('prefix') == 0) {
     console.log('prefix');
     console.log(element);
   }
});
 
 console.log("Second approach which is not suggested");
 array.forEach(function(element) {
   // not the correct approach as suggested by @Barmar though it works
   if (element.lastIndexOf('prefix',0) == 0) {
     console.log('prefix');
     console.log(element);
   }
});
```

Comment: @Barmar Added explanation and added your suggestion from the comments.

Comment: I don't see an explanation of what was wrong and how you fixed it. It seems like all you really did was add the missing `)`, which was probably just a copying error.

Comment: Thank you both, I think it has to do with the rest of my code, it works separate but once I put it in my code I get this error again (index):88 Uncaught TypeError: element.indexOf is not a function
    at (index):88
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at window.onload ((index):86)

Comment: Just checked and yes, my array didn't store the strings I was targeting...Thanks again for looking into it.

Comment: @Barmar That was the only error in her code. It was trivial and so did not bother putting it. However the optimal solution was provided by you so updated by answer with your suggestion.

Comment: @Alinacdn Can you mark this as accepted by clicking the tick mark below the vote button? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -4):

Try using double quotation marks instead of single like this "prefix" in functions.

Comment: Why would that make a difference? Single and double quotes are interchangeable in JavaScript.